# How to jump to certain time with the MPMoviePlayer of iPhoneSDK?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a iPhone based course video system, in which I need to associate slides with certain time position of the video. I have found no such function to jump to certain time position when playing a video. (Or like the custom control of that in the Joost app)
It would be a great favor for me if anyone can help me with it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no public API for this. There is a private API, `-currentTime` and `-setCurrentTime:` on MPMoviePlayerController, but as this is private your app is liable to get rejected from the AppStore if you use it (and you open yourself up to breaking on iPhone OS updates).

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Can you tell me what type of parameter should I pass to setCurrentTime? Thank you for you help.