# How do you determine a user's current location within a MPMoviePlayer instance?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a long movie that I'll be putting in an app, and I wanted to know what the best way to put the user back to the point they left off. Can someone point me in the right direction?

So if the user is watching the film, hit done, is there a notification of the current time or something that I can store and load the instance again with that time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found an OS 3.0 technique that doesn't make use of private API components.

You can register to receive MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification notifications and grab the MPAVControllerTimeParameter NSNumber out of that notification's userInfo Dictionary.

For example, just before you start playback register to receive the notifications:

```
#define MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification @"MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification"

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTimeChanged:) name:MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification object:nil];
```

Then start the movie playing.  Add a method that will be called for each time change as the movie plays:

```
-(void)handleTimeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary * userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    int lastPositionInSeconds = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"MPAVControllerTimeParameter"] intValue];
    NSLog( @"Last time was %d", lastPositionInSeconds );
}
```

And when the movie stops playing (you know this by listening for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notifications) stop listening for the MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification notifications.

Comment: Jason, this is great. Extremely helpful.

Comment: So to finish up, then you could store the lastPositionInSeconds, in a sql db, and when the user goes back to the video, you could set:
   moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = lastPositionInSeconds;
And that should work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This question duplicates or is related to the following other questions here:

- [chapters in videos for the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378746/how-to-jump-to-certain-time-with-the-mpmovieplayer-of-iphonesdk)
- [How to jump to certain time with the MPMoviePlayer of iPhoneSDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378746/how-to-jump-to-certain-time-with-the-mpmovieplayer-of-iphonesdk)
- [MPMoviePlayerController movie length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188543/mpmovieplayercontroller-movie-length)

To reiterate the answers from those questions, there is no current public API to start a movie at a specific frame or point in time.  While there are private APIs available (`-currentTime` and `-setCurrentTime`), they are subject to change and will get your app rejected during the approval process.

Comment: I think it's unfair to state "they will get your app rejected".  If you code carefully you can leverage these things in a safe way, and your app will not get rejected if it has a decent fallback (or at least doesn't crash).  There are tons of apps in the store with grey uses of the API.

Comment: During the app review process, Apple checks to the use of private APIs.  If found to be using a private API, your app will be rejected.  While there are certainly apps that make use of private APIs and slip through the review cracks, it should not be recommended to take advantage of private APIs, especially when they could change in a future OS update and cause your app to break.

It would not be beneficial to a proposed answer on StackOverflow to recommend the use of any private APIs.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, shek! It's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    `NSDictionary * userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    int lastPositionInSeconds = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"MPAVControllerTimeParameter"] intValue];
`// saving an NSInteger
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:lastPositionInSeconds forKey:@"currentMovieTime"];

    // getting an NSInteger
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"currentMovieTime"]; // default is zero if nil
        currentMovieTime = myInt;
        self.streamMoviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = currentMovieTime;
```

You can use this to set/get the variable and use that to start the movie at the right time. This will work even if the user restarts their phone or restarts the application.

Answer (score 0):

Slava,

I actually watched for all events getting fired by the system during movie playback and didn't see anything else that might help.  That MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification does get fired periodically during playback, but not as often as, say, every second.  It may get fired for each keyframe, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Jason, when I was trying this I noticed that when the user hit the done button, say they're halfway through the video:
2009-07-31 10:36:04.297 VideoApp[2398:207] Last time was 52
2009-07-31 10:36:11.933 VideoApp[2398:207] Last time was 60
2009-07-31 10:36:11.952 VideoApp[2398:207] Movie ended: Last time was 0
2009-07-31 10:36:12.597 VideoApp[2398:207] Last time was 0

They always seem to get 0 at the end. So there isn't a good way to tell if the movie actually ended, or they hit the done button. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I hadn't correctly stopped listening when I thought I had. I see that you still get one final output before the done notification is called. Thanks again!